# C++ - BigInt addition operation binary

Tags: c++, binary, biginteger

I have been trying to write a small BigInt class as practice. I wanted to implement it as a deque of bools, which represent the number's digits in binary. For example: 1234 becomes => 0100 0011 0010 0001. As you notice, I keep the digits of the number in reverse order, but the bits in the right order.

This makes constructing the class very fast, but operations became so tricky I couldn't figure out how to do them. So far I have this:

```
// Start from proper order + 3, because we store digits in reverse order.
BigInt operator+(int x) {
    BigInt res(*this);
    show_rep(res);
    unsigned bit_place = BIT_FOR_DIGITS - 1;
    auto res_it = res.num.begin() + bit_place;
    bool carry = 0;
    while (x | carry) {
        if (res_it != res.num.end() && res_it + 1 == res.num.end()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < BIT_FOR_DIGITS; ++i)
                res.num.push_back(0);
        }
        bool res_prev = *res_it;
        // combine bits with carry in
        *res_it ^= (x & 1) ^ carry;
        // figure out the carry out
        carry = ((res_prev ^ (x & 1)) & carry) | (res_prev & (x & 1));
        if (!bit_place) {
            // because we do the operations from the rightmost bit to the left
            // Ex: 1001 => 9, we start from right to left.
            res_it += 2 * BIT_FOR_DIGITS - 1;
            bit_place = BIT_FOR_DIGITS - 1;
        }
        else {
            --bit_place;
            --res_it;
        }
        x >>= 1;
    }
    show_rep(res);
    return res;
}
```

The BIT_FOR_DIGITS is a macro for 4. The above is a simple implementation of the hardware bitwise sum operation. However, the problem I'm facing is the following scenario:

- Suppose I wanted to add 127 and 5. The result is supposed to be 132. However, it outputs 1212. This is because, I use 4 bits to represent a digit. So, when the addition happens between 7 and 5, the result, 12, is just added at the end. The number isn't being reduced properly. I realize I need a mod operator for this, but I'm not sure how I can do it in binary. So, how can I properly handle addition with this kind of design? Or should I go for a better design altogether?

Comment: Suggestion -- overload `+=` instead of `+`.  When you overload `+=`, then write `+` in terms of `+=`.  Also, you need to first work this out on paper before writing any code -- you risk painting yourself in a corner when you first write code and then realize you're doing something that can't be undone easily.

Comment: Another thing is that eventually, you would want to have an `operator +(const BigInt&)` so that you can add two BigInt's together.  How would this code fit into those plans?

Comment: I realize I'll need to change many parts of this code. I'm just trying to get a good algorithm set first, then refactor for better use. As soon as this is done, the rest are really easy as they are all represented in similar ways. BigInt addition will be less tricky as both of their representations are the same.

Comment: Instead of representing each decimal digit as 4 bools, consider representing the entire value as bools, so `1234` would become `10011010010`. That should make much of the math easier. If your intention really is to do decimal digits as bools then disregard.

Comment: Initially my goal was going to be that, but I ran into this problem: How do I allow numbers that have more than 250 (arbitrary, but you get the point) digits supported in that format? How do I construct it with that logic? To solve that problem I used a representation like mine. However your representation handles operations a lot more efficiently compared to mine, as you said.

Comment: Why use decimal digits as bools? That is extremely inefficient.

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with big numbers, use bytes or 2-byte elements as digits/elements. That makes parsing and converting to string a little harder (but not very hard), but all other mathematical operations a lot easier. Adding two bytes produces a carry, which is then added to the sum of the next higher bytes, etc. Keep the sign separate, so you only have to add/subtract/multiply positive numbers and adjust the sign of the result.

Comment: I'm trying to make a good compromise between parsing speed and operation efficiency in my design. A more efficient design idea is also welcome.
Also, @RudyVelthuis, how exactly do I represent things in a byte size? Each digit occupying a byte? How will it work?

Comment: A byte has 256 different states. Two bytes have 256*256 = 65536 different states. The more bytes you add (to a dynamically allocated array, or, say, a vector), the bigger the number can be. Adding is simply adding the bytes at the same level and adding the carry over to the next higher bytes. You must of course keep track of the number of bytes, and make sure you only add if there is something in the vector, etc. Implementing a BigInt is no sinecure. It takes a lot of checks and consideration of corner cases, but the main work is generally quite simple (except division).

Comment: If you want operation efficiency, use 32 bit or 64 bit elements (or, as Knuth would say: limbs) in your vector, depending on the platform. Since you want to do this yourself, you will have to find out how to do this. I wrote my own (well optimized) BigInteger type too, but not in C++. It took me a LOT of reading to get everything right and fast. This is a very interesting field.